# Webpack errors while using sequelize with next.js?

Tags: node.js, next.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I am importing a model in pages/api/submitAllegationApi.js and creating a new entry there. Strangely enough there's no error when I use the 'api/submitAllegationApi' alone. Once I call another api route, and then use 'api/submitAllegationApi' again, I get the error below:

warn  - ./models/index.js
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
error - Error: Cannot find module '/Users/Desktop/.../.next/server/pages/api/pdfcreate.js'
at webpackEmptyContext (/Users/Desktop/.../.next/server/pages/api/submitAllegationApi.js:22:10)
at eval (webpack-internal:///(api)/./models/index.js:18:65)
at Array.forEach ()
at eval (webpack-internal:///(api)/./models/index.js:17:4)
at Object.(api)/./models/index.js (/Users/.../.next/server/pages/api/submitAllegationApi.js:84:1)
at **webpack_require** (/Users/.../.next/server/webpack-api-runtime.js:33:42)
at eval (webpack-internal:///(api)/./pages/api/submitAllegationApi.js:6:24)
at Object.(api)/./pages/api/submitAllegationApi.js (/Users/.../.next/server/pages/api/submitAllegationApi.js:95:1)
at **webpack_require** (/Users/.../.next/server/webpack-api-runtime.js:33:42)
at **webpack_exec** (/Users/.../.next/server/pages/api/submitAllegationApi.js:116:39) {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}

Below is my submitAllegationApi:

```
const db = require('../../models/index');
const { DataTypes } = require("sequelize");
const Allegations=require("../../models/Allegations")(db.sequelize, db.Sequelize.DataTypes);
export default async function handler(req, res){
     var data= req.body;
      Allegations.create({
        faculty: data.Faculty
        ...

    })
    console.log("received: "+data);
    res.status(200).send(data);
  };
```

Below is Allegation.js:

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Allegations extends Model {
 
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
    }
  }
  Allegations.init({
    faculty: DataTypes.STRING
    ...
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Allegations',
  });
  return Allegations;
};
```

And here's the index.js:

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];
const db = {};

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
```

module.exports = db;